# Is it possible to overload "" in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My intention is to implement a Big integer class.

If I try to assign value to an object it must be done in this way

```
Big_int n =1234567890123456;
```

And not in this way

```
Big_int n ="1234567890123456";
```

Comment: Have you looked into [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)?

Comment: @Nawaz, why? Something like `Big_int n =1234567890123456_bi;` can be easily implemented.

Comment: @Nawaz, [there is an overload taking `const char*` and arbitrary long strings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29c323bf5490ec27)

Comment: @Nawaz No; you can use a raw literal operator or a literal operator template.

Comment: We cant store big numbers directly and That is why i want to create a Big_int class so that i can store long number in form of string and manipulate it.

Comment: @Nawaz You don't. The compiler stringizes it for you.

Comment: @Nawaz See http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#3; essentially, use the `unsigned long long` if available; otherwise pass raw characters.

Comment: @Nawaz: UDLs are C++11.

Answer (score 5):

It is best to use user-defined literals for this. They are available in C++ since C++11. For accepting arbitrarily long sequences of digits you need to use literal function accepting `const char*`.

The following code gives you a draft of what you need with user-defined literals:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class BigInt {
 const std::string str;
 BigInt(const std::string& s) : str(s) { }
 friend BigInt operator "" _bi(const char* s);
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BigInt& bi);
};

BigInt operator "" _bi(const char* s) {
 return BigInt(s);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BigInt& bi) {
 return os << bi.str;
}

int main() {
 BigInt bi1 = 123_bi;
 BigInt bi2 = 123123412345123456123456712345678_bi;
 //BigInt bi3 = std::string("123");
 std::cout << bi1 << ' ' << bi2;
 return 0;
}
```

The literal operator function `operator ""` accepts string literals. I made it a friend of BigInt class, so the constructor accepting strings is not available to users of your class - but you may use sequence of digits with `_bi` suffix. The only drawback is that literal operator function with `const char*` argument is a fallback function for both integer and floating point literals, so still one can use things like

```
BigInt bi = 123.45_bi;
```

To block it you may declare additional

```
class Dummy {};
Dummy operator "" _bi(long double d) {
 return Dummy();
}
```

Provided that your BigInt class cannot be initialised with a `Dummy`, if you try to use BigInt with floating-point `_bi` literal it will be a compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a [suffix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

C++ doesn't allow the customization of the parsing rules so a very big number cannot be handled unless a (possibly custom) suffix is also added.

It's not possible to say "use this class if the digits are too many for the precision of a standard integer".

Comment: As pointed out in other comments, and since OP does not want to use string literals, UDL will not work, because you can not define an UDL for an integer larger than `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @sbabbi: you can. You need to define a raw literal operator and the compiler will pass it the characters instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the beginning of how I might tackle this.

c++14's constexpr means all manipulation can be done at compile time so there's no performance cost to pay for the (reasonably good) readability.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

struct big_int {

    constexpr big_int(int x = 0) {}

    constexpr big_int(std::initializer_list<int> il)
    : big_int(0)
    {
        for (int i : il) {
            assert(i < 1000);
            assert(i >= 0);
            (*this) *= 1000;
            (*this) += i;
        }
    }


    // todo - add implementation here
    constexpr big_int& operator*=(int i) { return *this; }
    constexpr big_int& operator+=(int i) { return *this; }

    // todo - data structure here

};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto bi = big_int({123, 456, 789,  98, 765, 654}); // care: missing leading zero!

    return 0;
}
```